# Perl's JSON::XS not encoding UTF8 correctly?

Tags: json, perl, cgi

This simple code segment shows an issue I am having with JSON::XS encoding in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS; 
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(utf8)";

my (%data);

$data{code} = "Gewürztraminer";
print "data{code} = " . $data{code} . "\n";

my $json_text = encode_json \%data;
print $json_text . "\n";
```

The output this yields is:

```
johnnyb@boogie:~/Projects/repos > ./jsontest.pl 
data{code} = Gewürztraminer
{"code":"GewÃ¼rztraminer"}
```

Now if I comment out the binmode line above I get:

```
johnnyb@boogie:~/Projects/repos > ./jsontest.pl 
data{code} = Gew�rztraminer
{"code":"Gewürztraminer"}
```

What is happening here? Note that I am trying to fix this behavior in a perl CGI script in which binmode can not be used but I always get the "Ã¼" characters as above returned in the JSON stream. How do I debug this? What am I missing?

Comment: Replace last line with `print decode('UTF-8', $json_text, Encode::FB_CROAK) . "\n";`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`encode_json` (short for `JSON::XS->new->utf8->encode`) encodes using UTF-8, then you are re-encoding it by printing it to STDOUT to which you've added an encoding layer. Effectively, you are doing `encode_utf8(encode_utf8($uncoded_json))`.

### Solution 1

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(utf8)';  # Defaults
binmode STDOUT;                      # Override defaults
print encode_json(\%data);
```

### Solution 2

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(utf8)';    # Defaults
print JSON::XS->new->encode(\%data);   # Or to_json from JSON.pm
```

### Solution 3

The following works with any encoding on STDOUT by using `\u` escapes for non-ASCII:

```
print JSON::XS->new->ascii->encode(\%data);
```

---

In the comments, you mention it's actually a CGI script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;                      # Encoding of source code.
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';   # Default encoding of file handles.
BEGIN {
   binmode STDIN;                       # Usually does nothing on non-Windows.
   binmode STDOUT;                      # Usually does nothing on non-Windows.
   binmode STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # For text sent to the log file.
}

use CGI      qw( -utf8 );
use JSON::XS qw( ); 

{
   my $cgi = CGI->new();
   my $data = { code => "Gewürztraminer" };
   print $cgi->header('application/json');
   print encode_json($data);
}
```

Comment: Yes - that does work and, as stated below, I think I am encoding data that is already UTF8. Not sure how to get around that. Unfortunately STDOUT really has no meaning in a CGI script (?) so I'm not sure I can use the method above.

Comment: You're not making any sense. You wouldn't have the problem if you didn't use STDOUT. And yes, CGI does use STDOUT.

Comment: I have not been able to figure out to to use a CGI object as a filehande to hand to binmode. The encoded json data must be printed to the CGI object to be returned to the jQuery making the AJAX request. If you know how to do this I am all ears and eyes.

Comment: What are you talking about. We've already established that CGI uses STDOUT, so you use exactly the code I posted.

Comment: @Omortis CGI.pm doesn't send anything anywhere. Your code needs to `print` stuff. CGI.pm just gives you crappy old functions that generate HTML for you. Also keep in mind that CGI.pm is not in core any more. :)

Comment: ikegami: you are correct - I was half-asleep when I looked at this previously and didn't set it up correctly in my CGI script. Since this is old code that is being ported to a new language the last ASCII encode swizzle is the way to go. Thanks - I appreciate it - nothing like some sleep!

Comment: simbabque: agreed - I don't even use it for printing HTML, only for acquiring form data. As stated above we are moving away from perl for this stuff anyway. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

`JSON::XS` encodes its output into octets. It means the external representation of encoded utf8 string, but it is not unicode string. For more details see [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html). In short, content of `$json_text` is prepared for transmitting by `IO` handler in binary code. If you create scalar content of `$data{code}` after `use utf8;` you have scalar containing internally encoded unicode characters string. (Which is internally encoded as utf8 but it is implementation detail you should not rely on. Pragma `use utf8;` means the source code is encoded as `utf8` and nothing else.) If you would like to output both scalars in `utf8` encoded `IO` handler you have to transform `$json_string` into internal unicode chracters string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS; 
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(utf8)";

my (%data);

$data{code} = "Gewürztraminer";
print "data{code} = " . $data{code} . "\n";

my $json_text = encode_json \%data;
utf8::decode($json_text);
print $json_text . "\n";
```

Or how it is intended to use, output encoded string using IO handler in binary mode.

```
my $json_text = encode_json \%data;
binmode STDOUT;
print $json_text . "\n";
```

Try

```
print utf8::is_utf8($json_text) ? "UTF8" : "OCTETS" . "\n";
```

to see what is inside.

Comment: Rather wasteful to ask to UTF-8 encode it only to follow up with a decode and yet another encode!

Comment: Yes, but points is to explain what is wrong rather make it efficient.

Comment: The code doesn't explain that, the explanation does.

Comment: The pragma "use utf8" was only included so that I could use the ü in the included source code pasted here and is not included in the original CGI perl code. I agree that it does muddy the water a bit as an example.

In the CGI source (which would be difficult to meaningfully share) the UTF8 data is coming from a DBI database query and is correct until passed through encode_json. The data is correct in the hash %data (as shown by CGI utils) but is not correct once encoded and shows exactly the behavior above (first run). Is the problem that I am trying to encode data that is already UTF8?

Comment: Hynek I just noticed your use of binmode - this is very similar to my original CGI - I tried it but no change...

Comment: Never ever use `is_utf8`. If you need to force the use of one of the two storage formats, use `utf8::upgrade` or `utf8::downgrade`, neither of which are needed here.

Comment: @ikegami: `is_utf8` doesn't forces anything! `is_utf8` _Test whether $string is marked internally as encoded in UTF-8._ according to the documentation. It reads the flag!

Comment: @Omortis: You read data from DBI? Here we go. Check if your data read from DBI is flagged internally as Unicode using `is_utf8` and if not then use `utf8::upgrade` . It is usual bug in DBI drivers. Then use approach in @ikegami's answer and choose if you would like to have IO in binary or utf8 mode.